# Hide an element in DOM when specific class included

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide a div from DOM when specific class included in middle of the html code. Please take a look at this example.

```
<body>
 <div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="text-block">Hello mars</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

I tried to achieve this with jQuery `.closest()` but no luck.

```
$( ".text-block" ).closest( ".first-group" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

Any solution?

Comment: You want to hide or add css property?

Comment: if you know the specific class, then can't you add hide function directly for the same?

Comment: Yes hide using css display:none

Comment: So, here you want to hide `.first-group` when there is `.text-block`?

Comment: `<div class="first-group">` is an individual div. It does not relate to `<span class="text-block">Hello mars</span>`. Are you sure you want to delete `first-group` ?

Comment: @jay My real problem is with some library. That generate the above class(first-group) I simplified my question and put it here.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if($(".second-group span").hasClass("text-block")) {
  $('.first-group').css('display', "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="text-block">Hello mars</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This will hide all instances of `.first-group`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply if the length of `.text-block` inside the wrapper is greater then 0 then simply make `.first-group` `display: none`.

```js
if($( ".wrapper" ).find( ".text-block" ).length > 0){
  $('.first-group').css( "display", "none" )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="text-block">Hello mars</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

If you have multiple `.first-group` and `.wrapper` then you can simply loop the wrapper and find its parent and previous element of that parent.

```js
$( ".wrapper" ).find( ".text-block" ).each(function() {
  $(this).parents('.wrapper').prev('.first-group').css( "display", "none" );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="text-block">Hello mars</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="text-block">Hello mars</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This will hide all instances of `.first-group`.

Comment: @JonP actually the OP mentioned that `.first-group` was generated by certain plugin and he want to hide that in comment. So, I have mentioned the above solution.

Comment: That's no matter :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @Janath updated little of jQuery, for multiple instances :)

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks for an ancestor. `.text-block` is not a descendant of `.first-group` . Use [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to find the previous sibling of the containing block.

**In response to your comment** <s>`prevAll` works if there are intermediate siblings.  I've added a few empty `divs` to the example to demonstrate. I need to check some fringe cases.</s>

To get this a bit more robust I've used [prevUntil](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) to limit the sibling selection combined with `prev` to find the actual element of interest.

```js
$( ".text-block" ).closest( ".wrapper" ).prevUntil(".first-group").prev().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<!-- This Won't Show -->
 <div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </div>
<div></div><div></div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="text-block">Hello mars</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--This Will Show-->
  <div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world, Again</h1>
 </div>
 <div></div><div></div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="not-text-block">Hello jupiter</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- This Won't Show -->
 <div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </div>
<div></div><div></div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="text-block">Hello mars</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--This Will Show-->
  <div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world, Again</h1>
 </div>
 <div></div><div></div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="not-text-block">Hello jupiter</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>


</body>
```

**NOTE** this will break if you change your HTML structure.

Comment: That's the case. How can I change this when I have other few divs behind wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

The use of closest will only look for its ancestor, while .first-group is outside the .wrapper div.

In the below code, we are finding the ancestor of the element and then use prev() to get previous element with class .first-group

```
 $(this).closest("div.wrapper").prev(".first-group").css('display', 'none');
```

See if it works.

Comment: Top tip, answers that explain what is broken and how you fixed it are better than "Try this and see if it works"

Comment: Now the only problem is, that it is the same in essence as my answer that precedes yours by about 5 min.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `parents()` and `siblings()` like the following:

```js
$(".text-block").parents('.wrapper').siblings('.first-group').css( "color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="first-group">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="second-group">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="small">
        <span class="text-block">Hello mars</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```